# Tab Bar Controller Position

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbarcontroller

I am new to iphone development.I want to know about Tab Bar Controller's position. is it convention or a rule to place the tab bar controller at bottom?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Its a apple recommendation but not a hard stick rule.. YOu can customize your view as much as you want untill it doesn't break any Apples rules list..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain about your implementation, but using a UITabBarController is the standard way to implement tabs. UITabBarController's tab bar is at the bottom of the view, and this is what iOS users are accustomed to. This will make your apps more consistent with the platform and because of this users will be able to navigate your app intuitively. There are definitely cases where tabs appear at the top (for example, if a view needs tabs but is already in a tab controller). Either way, you are free to put them where you like and Apple won't likely care as long as you are following the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Anatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH24-SW1).

Comment: @user3030016 you're welcome! if my answer gave you the information you needed, feel free to accept it as the right answer by clicking the check mark